# Call IronPython function from C# and Vice versa

Tags: python, .net, callback

I'm designing a Unity3D game where the user can adjust gameplay by modifying a .py file.

I'm using [Python Interpreter](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/89455-Python-Interpreter-in-Unity-Free-until-31-5!) asset, which wraps IronPython.

I need to pass control between C# and the running Python instance.  Here is a pseudocode example:

```
// From Unity, C# script... 
bool MakeNoise( float vol ) {
    //...
}
void Awake() {
    m_pythonEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
    m_scriptScope = m_pythonEngine.CreateScope();
}
bool NewRound( int n ) {
    myPythonRuntime.InvokeFunction( "NewRoundPy", param: roundNumber = n );
    return retVal;
}
```

And then, in the game while it is running, the user could enter in a textbox:

```
# Python
vol = 0.5

def NewRoundPy( roundNumber ):
    theCSharpObject.MakeNoise( vol )
    return True
```

Which would in turn invoke the MakeNoise function every time a new round starts.

Apologies for the clumsy hypothetical situation. The important thing is that I need to be able to transfer execution from one environment to the other, passsing data as I do so.

I'm aware of the code needed to run a Python script. But I want to invoke individual functions from the script. And the script has to stay running between such calls, so that variables set in one function/call are retaining their values the next time some function is called.

Is this possible? If so, how?

PS going Python -> C# seems to be fairly simple; [IronPython .NET Integration documentation](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#invoking-net-methods)

PPS I will tidy up the question once I have some understanding of what's going on

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53611/Embedding-IronPython-in-a-C-Application)?